# Error getting : How to get APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED for mailgun api to integrate with play framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, email, jersey-2.0, mailgun

While I was processing one API for Play Framework using mailgun I have onw question : what is this `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`

My code is following :

```
        Client client = Client.create();
    client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("api","my api key"));

    WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://api.mailgun.net/v2/lists");

    MultivaluedMapImpl formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
    formData.add("address", "samplelist@codenvy.mailgun.org");
    formData.add("description", "Sample Mailgun list");

    webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);

    webResource = client.resource("https://api.mailgun.net/v2/lists/" +
                             "samplelist@codenvy.mailgun.org/members");
    formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
    formData.add("address", "abc@xyz.com");
    formData.add("subscribed", true);
    formData.add("name", "ABC");
    formData.add("description", "Sample Member");
    formData.add("vars", "{\"age\": 26}");
    ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
    String output = clientResponse.getEntity(String.class);

    setMessage("Your list has been created successfully and a member has been added to it : " + output);
    return "SUCCESS";
```

Answer (score 0):

APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED are the parameters accepted represented as form data
For example the string
`I like form parameters - or not!` becomes `"I+like+form+parameters+-+or+not+%21"`